# CMemCache requires PHP memcache extension to be loaded

Tags: кэширование, yii

Подключено в конфиге:

```
'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.caching.CMemCache',
            'servers'=>array(
                array('host'=>'localhost', 'port'=>11211),
            ),
```

Расширений и прочего как-то не нашла для него

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну у вас ведь в прямым текстом написано, что для работы CMemCache требуется расширение memcache для PHP.
ОС какая используется у вас?

в debian-подобных ОС устанавливается расширение так:

```
sudo apt-get install memcached php5-memcache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Сам сервер memcache установлен? Вот здесь: http://habrahabr.ru/post/25296/ написано, как установить memcache в windows, и сделать так, чтоб php смог увидеть его)

Comment: Почитайте ссылку, что Я выше привел. Там написано, как установить memcache с самого начала, от установки сервера memcached - и до подключения расширения memcache для php.